# numbers not allowed (0-9) - Regex Expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex pattern which will allow me any chars, but it will not allow (0-9) numbers?

Comment: A little reading up on JavaScript regex ought to get you somewhere...

Comment: The words you're looking for are 'want a' (and I'd bet a very large sum that search would be your friend - VERY LARGE)

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: note that SLaks called you on the mat AND answered question AND explained the answer....maybe...accept one of these this time.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Simply:

```
/^([^0-9]*)$/
```

That pattern matches any number of characters that is not `0` through `9`.

I recommend checking out http://regexpal.com/.  It will let you easily test out a regex.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: @LuisTeijon There is not a thing called negative numbers when you enter minus - 

Regex recognizes it as a character, So, there's a number following after the minus. Hope it clears.

Answer (score 77):

Like this: `^[^0-9]+$`

Explanation:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `[^...]` matches anything that *isn't* inside
- `0-9` means any character between 0 and 9
- `+` matches one or more of the previous thing
- `$` matches the end of the string

Answer (score 21):

`\D` is a non-digit, and so then `\D*` is any number of non-digits in a row. So your whole string should match **`^\D*$`.**

Check on http://rubular.com/r/AoWBmrbUkN it works perfectly.

You can also try on http://regexpal.com/ OR http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 3):

It is better to rely on regexps like `^[^0-9]+$` rather than on regexps like `[a-zA-Z]+` as your app may one day accept user inputs from users speaking language like Polish, where many more characters should be accepted rather than only `[a-zA-Z]+`. Using `^[^0-9]+$` easily rules out any such undesired side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in javascript:

`var regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;`

and have a keyup event.

`$("#nameofInputbox").value.replace(regex, "");`

Answer (score -1):

Something as simple as `[a-z]+`, or perhaps `[\S]+`, or even `[a-zA-Z]+`?

Comment: Doesn't match any character, just letters or non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Nor will it get non-English chars.  like those crazy circles with the `/` threw them.